# how to overwrite system default keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V by using Javafx KeyCombination?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

While implementing undo/redo mechanism, I have written below code to add paste operation to my own undo stack. If I click on menu item it's executing event handling code, but if I use shortcut Ctrl+V my event handler is not executing.

For more information see the below code.

[image]

```java
        MenuItem paste = new MenuItem("Paste");

        KeyCombination pasteKeyCombination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.V,KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);

        paste.setAccelerator(pasteKeyCombination);

        paste.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("Ctrl+V triggered.");
            if(clipboard.hasString()){
                String pastedText = clipboard.getString();
                InsertCommand insertCommand = new InsertCommand(textArea.getCaretPosition(),pastedText,textArea);
                insertCommand.execute();
                UndoRedo.insertIntoUndoStack(insertCommand);
            }
        });
```

If I use different KeyCode like Ctrl+J it's working fine but not for Ctrl+V.

**Note:** When I use Ctrl+V it seems directly pasting data from system clipboard instead of executing my code.

Can anyone please suggest the solution for this problem? and please explain why it's working with Ctrl+J and why not Ctrl+V?

The issue exists for all cut, copy, paste shortcuts.

Comment: Regarding what's causing the problem, the behavior of `TextArea` adds various handlers implementing cut/copy/paste/undo/redo/etc. and these handlers consume the event. This means those events never reach the scene, which is a problem in this case because accelerators are only invoked if a matching event bubbles up to the scene.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for the comment. In this case how can we overwrite this behavior on textarea?

Comment: All default key bindings are stored in `TextInputControlBindings` class. `TextInputControlBehavior` and its child class `TextAreaBehavior` use those bindings. Unfortunately, extending `TextAreaBehavior` to change a key binding seems not to be an option (checked on JDK-8) because `TextAreaSkin` doesn't allow you to specify a custom behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the behavior of `TextArea` (which is an internal class) adds a number of `EventHandler`s which handle various user-generated events (e.g. key presses). This includes the common shortcuts used for cut, copy, paste, undo, redo, select all, and so on. These handlers then [consume](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.base/javafx/event/Event.html#consume()) the event which stops said event's propagation. Since menu item accelerators only work when the event bubbles back up to the `Scene`, the event being consumed by the `TextArea` behavior means your menu items don't fire.

One workaround is to use a custom `EventDispatcher` on the `TextArea` to filter out any key events which match any of a number of key combinations. All other events are allowed to proceed normally, leaving the rest of the behavior intact. This works by preventing the event from reaching the `TextArea` and letting the event enter the bubbling phase of event propagation, ultimately letting the event bubble back up the scene graph. That last bit is why using an `EventDispatcher` is necessary instead of an event filter; consuming an event in an event filter will stop the event from reaching the `TextArea` but won't let it bubble back up the scene graph.

Here's an example:

```java
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventDispatchChain;
import javafx.event.EventDispatcher;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    MenuItem cutItem = new MenuItem("Cut");
    cutItem.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.valueOf("shortcut+x"));
    cutItem.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("CUT"));

    MenuItem copyItem = new MenuItem("Copy");
    copyItem.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.valueOf("shortcut+c"));
    copyItem.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("COPY"));

    MenuItem pasteItem = new MenuItem("Paste");
    pasteItem.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.valueOf("shortcut+v"));
    pasteItem.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("PASTE"));

    TextArea area = new TextArea();
    area.setEventDispatcher(
        new FilteringEventDispatcher(
            area.getEventDispatcher(),
            cutItem.getAccelerator(),
            copyItem.getAccelerator(),
            pasteItem.getAccelerator()));

    VBox root = new VBox(new MenuBar(new Menu("Edit", null, cutItem, copyItem, pasteItem)), area);
    VBox.setVgrow(area, Priority.ALWAYS);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private static class FilteringEventDispatcher implements EventDispatcher {

    private final EventDispatcher delegate;
    private final Set<KeyCombination> blacklistedCombos;

    public FilteringEventDispatcher(EventDispatcher delegate, KeyCombination... blacklistedCombos) {
      this.delegate = delegate;
      // Set.of was added in Java 9
      this.blacklistedCombos = Set.of(blacklistedCombos);
    }

    @Override
    public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail) {
      if (!(event instanceof KeyEvent) || isPermitted((KeyEvent) event)) {
        return delegate.dispatchEvent(event, tail); // forward event to TextArea
      }
      return event; // skip TextArea and enter the bubbling phase
    }

    private boolean isPermitted(KeyEvent event) {
      return blacklistedCombos.stream().noneMatch(combo -> combo.match(event));
    }
  }
}
```

If necessary, you can filter more specifically by testing the `EventType` of the event (e.g. only filter `KEY_PRESSED` events). You could also whitelist combos instead of blacklisting them, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

As I couldn't find proper solution, I have tried some work around for now by adding onKeyPress event handler and it's executing the handler implementation even for Ctrl+C,Ctrl+V etc.

```java
        MenuItem paste = new MenuItem("Paste");
        this.textArea.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,event -> {
            if(event.isControlDown()&& event.getCode()==KeyCode.V){
                System.out.println("Ctrl+V is triggered");
                if(clipboard.hasString()){
                    String pastedText = clipboard.getString();
                    InsertCommand insertCommand = new InsertCommand(textArea.getCaretPosition(),pastedText,textArea);
                    insertCommand.execute();
                    UndoRedo.insertIntoUndoStack(insertCommand);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Note:** still not clear about why it's not working with KeyCombination. if anyone has answer please post it.